# python bokeh; change Patch colours with CustomJS callback on GMapPlot

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

I'm trying to add a button to my bokeh plot that will allow me to change the colour used on a patch glyph that I've added to a GMapPlot using a callback.

Currently what I have is:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import GMapPlot, GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d, Patch

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=-41.281909, lng=174.775993, zoom=13)
p = GMapPlot(x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(), map_options=map_options, api_key=API_KEY)
lats = [-41.281909, -41.281044, -41.294968]
longs = [174.775993, 174.761222, 174.764916]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lats=lats, longs=longs))
patch = Patch(x='longs', y='lats', fill_color='red', fill_alpha=0.2)
p.add_glyph(source, patch)
output_file('gmapplot.html')
show(p)
```

I'd like to be able to edit that fill_color through a callback using a button. I tried appropriating [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147984/bokeh-how-to-change-column-used-for-glyph-colors-with-customjs-callbacks) but haven't been able to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. If you're trying to run this code you will need to use your own google maps API key. You can get one [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Answer (score 0):

The other response changes the `fill_color` of a bunch of circles to refer to a different *column* of colors in a column data source (so that all the circles can have their own color) by changing the `field` attribute. Since you are trying to set just a single color value for the once `Patch`, you probably want to set `value` instead of `field`

```
cb = CustomJS(args=dict(patch=patch), code ="""
    patch.glyph.fill_color.value = 'blue';
""")
```

I guess it's possible you might need a `trigger` there but I don't think so.

The `patch` and `line` glyphs are the two glyphs that are a little quirky in the API, because they don't really support vectorized properties like all the other glyphs do.

---

UPDATE: Perhaps a complete example is clearer. Also FYI the `trigger` is needed, at least as of current versions (`0.12.4`).

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure

plot = figure()

r = plot.patch(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[1, 2, 2, 1],
               fill_color="firebrick", fill_alpha=0.6, line_color="black")


select = Select(title="Select colors", value="firebrick",
                options = ["firebrick","navy", "olive"])

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(renderer=r, select=select), code ="""
    renderer.glyph.fill_color.value = select.value;
    renderer.trigger('change')
""")
select.callback = callback

output_file("foo.html")

show(column(select, plot))
```

The patch starts out red. Changing the `Select` widget in the UI causes the color of the patch to update:

[image]

If that's not what you are asking then I have to gently suggest that the question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I probably oversimplified my question a bit before asking it since I do in fact want to be able to control the colour change programatically. Do I need to add list of colours to ColumnDataSource?Also, if I have multiple patches, how would I change them all with the callback?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I showed how you can change it programmatically, in a `CustomJS` callback that you could attach, e.g. to a Bokeh `Button`. My only comment was that `patch` only draws a single patch, which is why you want to set `value` instead of `field`, in contrast to things like `circle`, which can draw lots of circles at once.