# Select line color in a bokeh server

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm trying to allow the users to select line colors in a bokeh server. My try, adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455881/python-bokeh-change-patch-colours-with-customjs-callback-on-gmapplot), is the following. However, the line color doesn't update. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Also, is ti possible to pass some dictionary for the select, so the options won't be hex code/

```
from bokeh.io import show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import  ColumnDataSource, Legend, CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
from bokeh.layouts import row
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'Ay' : [1, 5, 3], 'A': [0.2, 0.1, 0.2], 'By' : [2, 4, 3], 'B':[0.1, 0.3, 0.2]})

columns = ['A', 'B']

tools_to_show = 'box_zoom,save,hover,reset'
p = figure(plot_height =300, plot_width = 1200, 
           toolbar_location='above',
           tools=tools_to_show)

legend_it = []
color = Category10[10]
columns = ['A', 'B']
source = ColumnDataSource(df0)
c = []
for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    c.append(p.line('x', col, source=source, name=col, color=color[i]))
    legend_it.append((col, [c[i]]))


legend = Legend(items=legend_it, location=(5,114))#(0, -60))

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

select = Select(title="color", value=color[0],
                options = color)
callbacks = CustomJS(args=dict(renderer=c[0], select=select), code ="""
    renderer.glyph.color.value = select.value;
    renderer.trigger('change')
""")

select.callback = callbacks

layout = row(select, p)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the JavaScript code is wrong, please change it to :

```
renderer.glyph.line_color = select.value;
```